# How to subtract coordinates from eachother

Tags: google-maps, coordinates, subtraction

Im stuck with the following problem:

I use boundingbox coordinates from a certain route in google maps to get Points of interest information from an api. This api tells then if there are any POI in the boundingbox. But Because it's a box, it also shows POI's which are not on the specific route. So Lets say for example we have a route, from birmingham to London and we know it has 2 POI's on it. When I use the route boundingbox coordinates from google maps to get the POI's I also get Other POI's which are not on the route but are in the box.

Can anyone please explain how I can subtract these coordinates from eachother, so Remove the coordinates from the POI's which are not on the route. So I only keep the POI's on my route.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You may use [`google.maps.geometry.poly.isLocationOnEdge()`](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference?hl=en&csw=1#poly) .

Iterate over all returned POI's and check if the POI is near the route(must be a Polyline, e.g. based on the `overview_path` of the route). Use an appropriate `tolerance` to get the desired result, the default-tolerance probably will not be the best choice.